# Notifications or Service Hooks in TFS for comments on a pull request in a Git repository in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

Is there an option in TFS to trigger an email notification when a team member comments on an open pull request **in a git repository**?  I know this was [recently added](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/news/2017/may-11-team-services#default-notifications-for-pr-comments), but it appears to only be available on TFVC repositories.  Obviously this feature is critical to most team workflows - has any one found a way to set this up or a work around?

Comment: Are you using on-premise TFS or VSTS?

Answer (score 0):

TFVC doesn't have PRs, so the notification you're talking about is for Git repos. When a user comments on your PR, you are notified of the comment.

Check your user profile notifications to make sure that notification is turned on for you. It's not on the settings page, it's actually an option under your user profile (when you mouse-over your user image in the top-right corner, under "Notifications").

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on TFVC. I did try the notifications for my user profile, the option is not available for me there.  When I try to add a new notification (User Image > Notifications > +New) from that page, I do not see the option under either the available options for "Code (Git)".  I see only the following options: 1) A commit authored by me is pushed 2) A commit is pushed by me 3) A commit is pushed 4) A pull request is created or updated.